# Why is 80gb HD read BIG error rate & smart data different and everything SLOW?

Tags: usb, 13.04, hard-drive

Load & run ok via USB stick (real slow, jerkey), then installed (4th time now) having problem.  Able to boot from 80 gb SATA HD but everything still slow, jerkey, takes 1 second per charactor on dash. After several restarts, fails to boot at all. (Did install Invidia's Driver though.)

Performed Clean install each time by itself. (Ran disk diag, benchmark crashes. SMART data report is different than Seagate's SMART data report, (and long HD test via DOS which passed NO ERRORS or bad sectors): Ubuntu test had Read error rate 89371540, Hardware ECC recovered 89371540! two bad sectors, but PASSED the HD!  Thinking this is where my problem may be.  Must be something obvious I have to correct.  Learning the dash!

Humbly request suggestion,

Thanks,
holmzie

Comment: did you test your ram ? if not please do before thinking you have a faulty hard drive..  test it and tell us if the ram is fine.. 2 bad sectors usually doesn't slow down a drive.. usually ubuntu will just isolate the bad sectors and not use them.. so the rest of the hard drive should be fine and not slow at all..

Comment: also do you know what is the sata controler's chipset ? are you using the one on the motherboard or one from an addon pci card ?